# using System import not recognized in class library project(visual studio)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I cloned a repository from gitlab and I have a project (class library) that targets .NET Framework 4.5 but I get some errors from that project like

```
  -> using System.Net  not recognized AND
  -> Error  CS0012  The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

I looked into registry editor and I have .NET Framework 4.7.2 installed ..even though in control panel -> programs I have installed .NET Framework 4.6.1 and 
4.6.2 (developer package) cause I needed for other projects
[.NET Frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxmty.png).. But this might be the issue ?  Anyway I tried to install from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30653 NET framework 4.5 but won't let me. Can anyone help me about what is happening ? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219340/net-standard-2-0-cannot-be-referenced-in-net-framework-2-0

Comment: Do you have automatic nuget restore turned off?

Comment: @Neil ..Yes....